# multiple versions of gradle plugin when building in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using the skillz sdk to develop a quiz game which requires gradle. My current version of unity is `2019.3.0.a5`. When I build the project I get the following errors.

```
   > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
      > Using multiple versions of the Android Gradle plugin in the same build is 
        not allowed.    
           'C:\Users\Zachary Edgell\cash quiz\Temp\gradleOut\launcher' is using 
            version 3.2.0

           'C:\Users\Zachary Edgell\cash quiz\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary' is 
            using version 3.2.1
```

I have attempted to down grade to unity `2019.1.8f1`when I try to build again I get the error

```
FileNotFoundException: Temp\gradleOut\build\outputs\apk\release\gradleOut-release.apk does not exist
```

When I try to do a development build on `2019.1.8f1` I get the following error

`FileNotFoundException:Temp\gradleOut\build\outputs\apk\release\gradleOut-debug.apk does not exist`

I have also attempted to delete the `temp` folder and rebuild but I get the same error.

Comment: Doesn't have to be related but I see it very often lately: [`2019.3.0aX`](https://unity3d.com/unity/alpha/2019.3.0a5) are **alpha** versions (thus the `a`)! They are for testing new features only, not unlikely to be full of bugs and errors and are **not stable** for production. Unless you are testing new features it will always be better to stick to the latest **release** version which is currently `2019.1.8`.

Comment: Did you try to delete the `Temp` folder? (**Backup first!**) It will be rebuilt the next time you build. The conflict you have might be caused by artefacts from earlier build attempts using an older gradle version.

Comment: I did delete the temp folder but upon trying to rebuild it still gives me the same error. I have tried to down grade but I get a error I will add the error I’m getting there to the question when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by downgrading to unity `2018.4.3f1` if any one is having this issue just back up your files then try to downgrade to unity `2018.4.3f1`